# why the property is not deleted from object which is present in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to delete property from objects which is present in array .Actually In my objects, each object contain a property `shortkeys` .I need to delete `shortkeys` property only when it not present in given object .In other words

I have one given object

```
var obj ={
  alt+c:"alt+c"
  alt+g:"alt+g"
}
```

I need to delete `shortkey` property from object only if it not present in given object key .

I tried like this

```
var arr=[
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+m"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+a"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+c"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+f"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+g"}
]
var obj ={
  alt+c:"alt+c"
  alt+g:"alt+g"
}

for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  var o =arr[i];
  for(key in obj){
    if(o.shortkeys !=key){
      delete o.shortkeys;
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
var expectedArr=[
  {name:"abc"},
  {name:"abc"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+c"},
  {name:"abc"},
  {name:"abc",shortkeys:"alt+g"}
]
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5134enew/1/

**Update** :

It delete from all object
https://jsfiddle.net/5134enew/2/

Comment: What is currently happening that should not be?

Comment: You should correctly indent your code.

Comment: Note: `alt+c` and `alt+g` aren't valid identifiers. They need to be in quotes also when used as keys for `obj` – `{ "alt+c": "alt+c", ... }`.

Comment: Fix syntax errors first, e.g. this
`var obj ={
alt+c:"alt+c"
alt+g:"alt+g"
}` is invalid.

Comment: `if(o.shortkeys !=obj[key]){` this will work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5134enew/2/

Comment: it delete from all objects please see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5134enew/2/

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax error, your code checks if there exists a key that is not the shortkey, rather than checking if the shortkey is in the list you want to check against. `alt+c` is checked against `alt+g`, and thus removed. You want to prevent deletion when it is found instead.

So instead of doing the following...

```
  for(key in obj){
    if(o.shortkeys !=key){
      delete o.shortkeys;
    }
  }
```

...you would do this instead.

```
  var match = false;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (o.shortkeys == key) {
      match = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!match) {
    delete o.shortkeys;
  }
```

This can be shortened to a simple `x in y` in check as @Mark Leiber suggested. You should realize that the deletion takes place after checking **all** keys, instead of deleting just whenever we encounter a key that does not match.

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "abc",
  shortkeys: "alt+m"
}, {
  name: "abc",
  shortkeys: "alt+a"
}, {
  name: "abc",
  shortkeys: "alt+c"
}, {
  name: "abc",
  shortkeys: "alt+f"
}, {
  name: "abc",
  shortkeys: "alt+g"
}]
var obj = {
  "alt+c": "alt+c",
  "alt+g": "alt+g"
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var o = arr[i];

  if(!(o.shortkeys in obj)) {
    delete o.shortkeys;
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Can't that `for` loop be condensed to simply check if the key is not in the object?: `if (!(arr[i].shortkeys in obj)) {delete arr[i].shortkeys;}`

Comment: In this case, yes. This probably does a better job at highlighting what error in thinking OP did though.

Answer (score 0):

As said above your code deletes the shortkeys when it doesn't match with the keys in obj. So (o.shortkeys)"alt+m"!==(key)"alt+c"-->hence delete o.shortkeys.And then again it goes for checking (shortkey which has been already been deleted so o.shortkeys is undefined)ie "undefined != alt+g" which has got no meaning and again tries to delete o.shorkeys ie undefined which makes no meaning.
I have written a more detailed code similar to the above one.
please check the fiddle : `jsfiddle.net/som99/d37ws7r6/2/`

Explanation are given in comments.Check the console for the output.